# How does Hibernate fetch data in a OneToMany relationship under the hood?

Tags: java, reflection, orm, one-to-many, hibernate-onetomany

I am developing an ORM library similar to Hibernate. Now I'm stuck with the OneToMany relationship. I'd like to know how to fetch automatically data from database when `getter` of the *one* side is called and how Hibernate does it under the hood.

**Many side**

```
public class Film {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @JoinColumn(name="producer_id")
    private Producer producer;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Producer getProducer() {
        return producer;
    }

    public void setProducer(Producer producer) {
        this.producer = producer;
    }
}
```

**One Side**

```
public class Producer {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="producer")
    private Set<Film> films;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // When called, it executes: SELECT ... FROM Film where producer_id = ?
    public Set<Film> getFilms() {
        return films;
    }
}
```

In other words, I want to fill `films` inside `Producer` **only** when `getFilms()` is called.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate uses proxies of entity classes instead of real entity class using bytebuddy by generating addintional code at runtime.

BTW, I am just curious why are you developing your own ORM when you can use hibernate itself? It's the best ORM out there covering almost all kind of use cases and different optimization techniques.

Comment: Thanks for the information about Bytebuddy, I didn't know that fact. I have to develop this library because it is a part of my assigned final project in college.